# Updating object with child collection using Entity Framework causing duplicates in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a `Customer` class that has a relationship to an `Address` class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Street1 { get; set; }

    //Snip a bunch of properties

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I have an edit form which displays all the fields for both the customer and address. When this form is submitted, it calls the `Edit` method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(Customer customer)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var viewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel
        {
            Customer = customer,
            CustomerTypes = _context.CustomerTypes.ToList()
        };

        return View("CustomerForm", viewModel);
     }

     if (customer.Id == 0)
         _context.Customers.Add(customer);
     else
     {
         var existingCustomer = _context.Customers
             .Include(c => c.Addresses)
             .Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);

         existingCustomer.Name = customer.Name;
         existingCustomer.TaxId = customer.TaxId;
         existingCustomer.CustomerTypeId = customer.CustomerTypeId;
         existingCustomer.CreditLimit = customer.CreditLimit;
         existingCustomer.Exempt = customer.Exempt;
         existingCustomer.Addresses = customer.Addresses;
     }

     _context.SaveChanges();

     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customers");
}
```

This doesn't work and creates duplicate entries in the `Addresses` table in the DB. I think I understand why (EF isn't smart enough to know the Addresses inside the collection need to be added/modified/deleted as the case may be). So, what is the best way to fix this?

My instinct is that I need to iterate over the `Addresses` collections and compare them manually, adding any new ones from the form that don't exist for the customer, updating ones that do exist, and deleting ones that were not sent by the form but exist in the DB for the customer. Something like (ignoring the delete functionality for now):

```
foreach(Address address in customer.Addresses)
{
    if (address.Id == 0)
        // Add record
    else
        // Fetch address record from DB
        // Update data
    }
    // Save context
```

Is this the best way to go about this, or are there any EF tricks to iterating and syncing a child collection to the DB?

Oh, and one question which has me scratching my head - I can sort of understand how a new address record is getting created in the DB, but what I don't get is the existing address record is also updated to have its `customer_id` set to NULL...how the heck does that happen? That leads me to believe that EF does see the original address record is somehow linked (as it is modifying it) but it's not smart enough to realize the record I'm passing in should replace it?

Thanks -- also, this is EF6 and MVC5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the line

```
     existingCustomer.Addresses = customer.Addresses;
```

in your code. This like assigns field `Addresses` from `customer` coming from the model. So far ok. The point is that `customer` does not have any relation to the database model at this point (it's not coming from the database but from the view).

If you would like to update `existingCustomer.Addresses` with the data coming from the model, you need to *merge* the data instead of replacing it. The following "pseudo code" might give you a direction:

```
void MergeAddresses(var existingAddresses, var newAddresses) {
   foreach(var address in newAddresses) {
      if (existingAddresses.Contains(newAddress)) {
         // merge fields if applicable
      }
      else {
         // add field to existingAddresses - be ware to use a "cloned" list
      }
   }
   // now delete items from existing list
   foreach (var address in existingAddresses.CloneList()) {
      if (!newAddresses.Contains(address)) {
         // remove from existingAddresses
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So this is similar to my instinct to iterate through addresses and manually compare each one -- I do like the idea of putting it in a helper method. Would the controller be the right place for this? Also, what exactly do you mean when you say "beware to use a cloned list"?

Comment: I would personally put this kind of logic to a separate (i.e. business layer) class. This would allow easy unit testing without mocking MVC classes. "Be aware" of changing a list currently processed with "foreach" or other enumeration operations. There's a dedicated exception (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986550/foreach-loop-collection-was-modified-exception)

Comment: Thanks, I would up using similar logic and got it working. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the best way to go about this, or are there any EF tricks to iterating and syncing a child collection to the DB?

No, there aren't such tricks. EF designers left saving detached entities totally up to us - the developers.

However there is a package called [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) which is addressing that, so you could give it a try. Here is how your code would look like using it:

```
using RefactorThis.GraphDiff;

...

_context.UpdateGraph(customer, map => map.OwnedCollection(
    e => e.Addresses, with => with.AssociatedEntity(e => e.Customer)));

_context.SaveChanges();
```